# Presto query error: Error reading tail from

Tags: database, amazon-s3, hive, databricks, presto

I'm trying to query data with Presto connection. The data(delta format) is in S3 bucket and fails with this error:

```
SQL Error [16777232]: Query failed (#20211005_122441_00037_s2r9w): Error reading tail from s3://*/*/*/table/*/part-00015-bc2cc6d2-706d-4859-ab57-5f87d93d81f5-c000.snappy.parquet with length 16384
```

When I look at the bucket the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, could you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data has been changed, but the metadata (I assume you're using AWS Glue as a metastore) hasn't.

You can try to `CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('<YOUR_SCHEMA>', '<YOUR _TABLE>', 'full');` to get it updated.

Also make sure you've got a consistent schema between your partitions if you're using them.